# Contradiction between Pearson's correlation coefficient and t-test results

Tags: correlation, t-test

I've been analysing data between cliff height and average erosion rate. The data is parametric so I used Pearson's correlation and found that I got a coefficient of 0.017. When I applied a 2-tailed t-test to the data I found that I had a t value of 28.22 with 128 degrees of freedom. The t-test is saying the data is significant when the correlation result is saying it is not

Any ideas?

Comment: What defines your two groups for the t test?  Can you post the data? Note that data are not "parametric" or "nonparametric"; at best those are terms that describe methods. (FWIW, I have a persona as geomorphologist.)

Comment: The t test is comparing two means; the correlation is quantifying linearity of relationship. They are asking different questions and there is no reason for the answers to be the same.

Comment: What does it mean "the data is significant"?

Answer (score 1):

The correlation coefficient appears to be what you're interested in here. If you entered these two measure types (height and erosion rate for each cliff) as two groups for a t-test, you'd almost certainly get a highly significant difference-- but all that means is that height measurements tend to be in a different range of numerical values from erosion rate measurements. That's an obvious, uninteresting result, and not the question you mean to ask.

Comment: If that guess is right -- noting that the OP has apparently abandoned the question -- then your comments understate the main point, which is that such a  t test is totally inappropriate. Means of variables with different units of measurement (indeed, worse, different dimensions) are not comparable, period.

Comment: Right - this wasn't clear enough, but I suppose my point is that the result of conducting the wrong statistical test will often still mean *something*, and the absurdity of what the result really means can be instructive. (Congratulations, your paired-samples t test found that a person's height in meters tends to differ from his weight in kilograms!)